# In Drupal 6, how do I make a specific content type always show with lightbox 2?

Tags: drupal, dynamic, lightbox, lightbox2

Doing node/%/lightbox2 would do it, but I can't figure out how to make a dynamic link to the node!

Ideally, each node will have a thumbnail, and that thumbnail will trigger the lightbox2-viewed node

Answer (score 1):

One of the options of such a "gallery of nodes" could be creating a View, which first filters by the node type you want. Second, you theme that view so that links to the node point to "node/number/lightbox2", also adding a rel="lightbox" attribute to enable the viewing with lightbox2.

Graphical thumbnail of a textual node is not a trivial task, it would require writing a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

That's good info, how about making it so that the node doesn't show with header, footer etc -- only the content of that one node? The only way I can see that right now is making a page.tpl.php which acts as a selector based on the type of node, but isn't that kind of messy?

The textual node won't be just textual -- there will be an image in it (forced), which I can have auto-thumbnailed and that thumbnail presented in the view. Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 0):

Showing it without the blocks, footers or header you have choices in making it a page-pane, or creating a custom page or use an override PHP template where you leave out the unwanted stuff.